# IntelliJ Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

This line compiles

```
List<Trade> trades = otrades.stream()
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.getMeta().getTradeDate()))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But adding a 'thenComparing' does not

```
List<Trade>trades = otrades.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.getMeta().getTradeDate())
                   .thenComparing(t -> t.getName()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Compiler error is that it can not resolve getMeta().

(As there don't appear to be any errors in the code I'm assuming the problem is in IntelliJ).

Thanks

Comment: Does it compile on the command line? You don't mention that it does or doesn't.

Comment: I don't know for sure I'm assuming there are no syntax errors in the line of code. I'll update the question.

Comment: Try it with javac. This is a particularly difficult type inference case, and different compilers handle it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reason I don't understand, type inference fails in the second case. But you can give the type of `t`

```
List<Trade>trades = otrades.stream()//*******
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(     (Trade t) -> t.getMeta().getTradeDate())
   .thenComparing(t -> t.getName()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

In your example, the compiler finds that `t` is something else that a `Trade` (probably `Object`). That's why the method `getMeta()` cannot be found.

Comment: Yes you're completely correct! Wonder why that is though?

Comment: I mark your question as favorite and I will inquire on this :)

Comment: @Dan Sorry for my misleading first answer, I thought there was a paren problem; however, does this error happen if you define the comparator outside `.sorted()`?

Comment: yes, that resolves the problem. But you didn't provide a reply why the original snippet didn't work